# Replacing a text placeholder with a chart from a sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a script that is supposed to fill a series of placeholders in the body of a Google Doc with various values from a Google Sheet. One of the objects that I wish to be merged into the template is an `EmbeddedChartBuilder` object:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
                 .addRange(range)
                 .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
                 .setPosition(i, 6, 0, 0)
                 .setOption('legend.position', 'none')
                 .setOption('height', 50)
                 .setOption('width', 700)
                 .setOption('colors', ['black', 'white'])
                 .setOption('hAxis.minValue', 0)
                 .setOption('hAxis.maxValue', 10)
                 .setOption('backgroundColor.fill', 'white')
                 .setOption('hAxis.gridlines.color', 'white')
                 .setOption('hAxis.gridlines.count', 0);
sheet.insertChart(chart.build());
```

The merge code is as follows:

```
body.replaceText('{name}', company.name);
body.replaceText('{score}', company.score);
body.replaceText('{applyTime}', company.applyTime);
body.replaceText('{confEmail}', company.confEmail);
body.replaceText('{mobiFriendly}', company.mobiFriendly);
body.replaceText('{chart}', chart);
```

The last line, `body.replaceText('{chart}', chart);`, of course simply replaces the placeholder in the Doc with "EmbeddedChartBuilder".

Is there a way to insert the chart to a placeholder as an image or something? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's more logical to have `.build()` at the end of the chain defining the `chart` variable. After all, you want to insert a chart, not a chart builder.

Of course, an attempt to insert a chart with replaceText function would coerce it to "EmbeddedChart" string. Instead, use [`appendInlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#appendInlineImage(BlobSource)) or [`insertInlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertInlineImage(Integer,BlobSource)) on an appropriate element. I'll use the former because it's simpler: it just appends the image at the end of the element to which it's applied.

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()........build();
var found = body.findText('{chart}');
if (found) {
  found.getElement().getParent().appendInlineImage(chart);
  body.replaceText('{chart}', '');
}
```

Here, `findText` retrieves a RangeElement pointing to {chart}; then we get the element (Text) containing that string, and then its Parent (likely a Paragraph, but could be a ListItem, etc). The image is appended to the Parent, and finally the string {chart} is removed with `replaceText`.

This  assumes that the string {chart} is at the end of its element (likely, it is in a paragraph of its own).

Comment: Thank you. After asking the question, I realized a lot of these things just as I was about to answer the question, but you likely worded it better than I would have!